# pg_dump script for database backup

Tags: backup, postgresql, database

How I can create an script to backup my postgres databases on linux systems using pg_dump

Already use the comand but i want someting execute itself no user interaction so

```
pg_dump -U postgres -W -Fc
```

This ask for password and if I use -w ask for a pgpass file

Answer (score 2):

It's an script for root user, place on /root directory:

```
#! /bin/sh

USER="postgres"
PASS="password"

## Staorage Dir
bkp_dir="/home/USER_HOME/databases-$(date +%Y%m%d)"
echo "Creating directory: ${bkp_dir}"
mkdir $bkp_dir

## Temporal credential access file
credentialsFile=".pgpass"
echo "*:*:*:$USER:$PASS" >> $credentialsFile
chmod 600 $credentialsFile

echo "Backing up databases"

pg_dump -U postgres -w -Fc > $bkp_dir/

rm $credentialsFile
```

You can create a crontab for autorun the script as your wish

Resources:
https://severalnines.com/database-blog/backup-postgresql-using-pgdump-and-pgdumpall
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-backup-database/

Comment: Since the password is in the script, you might just as well set it in the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable instead of writing it to .pgpass. See [Environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) in pg documentation.

Comment: how do you know if pg_dump completed successfully or not in this script?